# How can i use @EnableSwagger2 and @EnableConfigServer by the same time

Tags: java, spring-cloud, swagger-2.0

i am sorry that my english is not very well, but now i have a problem ,the problem is when i try to use the @EnableSwagger2 and @EnableConfigServer by the same time,i found that spring.cloud.config.server.prefix in the bootstrap.yml not work,it lead to all request of static resource be bad. so, how can i fix it.

Comment: My answer would be setting `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix`. I don't know how that would break static resources.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i think this [issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1262) may answer your question, but now when i add @EnableSwagger2 ,the setting `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` do not work ,so  all request of static resource be bad.

Comment: The answer to that issue was to set the prefix.

Comment: yes , i konw, i set it ,bug when i add @EnableSwagger2 ,the prefix not work